# Designing GUI for mobile apps working in bright sunlight environment

Tags: color-theory, interface-design, mobile, mobile-first

I'm going to create GUI for a mobile app that will work in bright sunlight environment (inside a car so it will not be *fully* exposed to sunlight) and the usability and visibility of certain GUI elements are the most important factors.

What are some tips for creating such UI? What colors should I use?

Answer (score 1):

A car's cockpit is a good orientation aid for this. Aim for high contrast. Black background and possibly white graphics/text. Black absorbs sunlight so it isn't reflected back to the user. Colored elements need to be a little bit larger than normal.

Comment: um, I think you got the black wrong. Black shiny surfaces make better mirrors...

Comment: @KMSTR: A black shiny surface is really a black surface (LCD panel, in this case) under a shiny surface (glass cover). Any specular reflections off the glass aren't much affected by the color of the LCD panel under it, except that they're easier to see against a dark background than against a light one. The real lesson here is that glossy screens suck in brightly lit environments.

Comment: Yes. I should have said the color choice was wrong and not just the choice of black.